# Truncating texts before and after a certain character python

Tags: python, regex, text, truncate

I have large texts that I am reading in python,

The format of the texts is :

```
blablabla
***** END HEADER ******

valid content


***** start footer *****
blablalba
```

I need to remove the headers and footers in all the texts by removing all the string until ***** END HEADER ***** and everything after ***** start footer *****

Any help would be appreciated

I tried this so far:

```
import re

chop = re.compile('(/.+)*** END HEADER *****', re.DOTALL)

data_chopped = chop.sub('', text_file)
```

But i keep getting the error:

```
sre_constants.error: multiple repeat at position
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @RobertSeaman I edited the question to include what i tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other efficient ways, one way may be to try using multiple splits:

```
txt = """blablabla
***** END HEADER ******

valid content


***** start footer *****
blablalba
"""

# split the header and take the second section of split
tmp = ''.join(txt.split('***** END HEADER ******')[1])
# split by footer and take the first section of split
tmp2 = ''.join(tmp.split('***** start footer *****')[0])
result = tmp2.strip()
print(result)
```

Result:

```
'valid content'
```